# AWX - Could not find imported module support code for version

Tags: docker, ansible, ansible-awx

i installed AWX and can run my playbooks. But for some reasons i get this Error-Message when i want to run my Playbook where the community.docker module is in the tasks.
I get the Error Message:
fatal: [local]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Could not find imported module support code for version.  Looked for either StrictVersion.py or version.py"}

I installed the module on my awx container (task and web) and also in my virtualenv. But nothing helped.

When i run the Playbook via ansible-playbook command it works fine.

Does anyone know an answer or a solution? thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is a way you can install a collection in your project repository.

```
├── collections/
```

you can create above directory in your project where you have parent / trigger playbooks and install docker collection in it using below command.

```
ansible-galaxy collection install community.docker -p collections
```

This will allow you to install maintain and update required collections at project level.

Comment: Tried it. But it still doesnt work. Also, when i enter the command. There is a Warning message:[WARNING]: The specified collections path '/var/lib/awx/projects/collections' is not part of the configured Ansible collections
paths '/root/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections'. The installed collection won't be picked up in an
Ansible run.